# WCF Not binding to urls

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, rest

I have a small I have just written which uses the following uri template.

```
[UriTemplate = "xml/{user_id}/{content_id}/{time}")]
```

On my local dev machine

```
/blahblah.svc/xml/1/1/1
```

On my remote machine

/myapp/blahblah.svc/xml/1/1/1

Works, however when I try to deply this to a remote machine I get a 500 error, when I look at the 500 error the server appears to be trying to look for a web.config in blahblah.svc/xml/.

It does not appear to be binding to the url correctly after the blahblah.svc.

In my web.config I have :-

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <services>
  <service name="JASWebservices.JCPSRest" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JASWebservices.IJCPSRest" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
```

So if I access this locally (on my dev machine) it works. 
If I access this remotely on the prod server it 500s. The only difference I can see at present is the inclusion of the /myapp/ at the beginning since the prod server has multiple sites on it each to their own web app.

Comment: A 500 status code might be that there is some exception thrown when the request is being processed on the server. Have you tried debugging the service? If hosted on IIS i guess the virtual directory path should not cause any problems. Make sure of the app pools target framework on the remote prod server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a strange one, so I've found a rather lacking problem in Microsoft WCF when using it for REST implementations using the UriTemplate + ServiceContract.

If you are using IIS and host this on a UNC path (ie a NFC or SMB or CIFS system) it does not work properly. You have to move the service to a local directory in order for it to run.

I tried this on two different boxes (one SMB and one NFS) using both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 and the same issue appears on both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line

```
<endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

after

```
<endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JASWebservices.IJCPSRest" behaviorConfiguration="web">
</endpoint>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't help as it only changed the meta data endpoint. The metadata part already worked it was the web part that didn't